# Need to edit my locales under /etc/environment

Tags: locale, environment

I'm a complete noob so sorry for the lack of understanding.

When setting my locales under /etc/environment I accidentally entered `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8`  The problem being that the second "UTF-8" shouldn't be there.

So currently I have 3 entries here.  The improper one mentioned above, and 2 that both say `en_US.UTF-8`

I believe the improper entry is causing errors and I want to remove it.  Any help on how to do this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/945991/edit ) your post, and paste, then format with `{}`, the contents of your `/etc/environment` file. The initial `/` matters.

Comment: How  did you "setting my locales under etc/environment"? Can't you just logically reverse the process? What have you tried?

Comment: I think you've got the wrong file... not `/etc/environment`... but maybe `/etc/default/locale`? Tell us what the PROBLEM is, and what the ERRORS are, and let us decide what/where the SOLUTION is. What file did you edit, and why?

Comment: I'm so sorry I suck! If I'm literally too stupid to even ask questions just let me know so I can stop wasting people's time.

Basically, I ran this `sudo sh -c "echo 'LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8\nLANG=en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8' >> /etc/environment"` And now the bad entry with the extra "UTF-8" it's saved under LC_ALL 

I think it's causing the following error
`Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Because earlier in the code I can see 

`Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-6) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: UTF-8: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127`

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `cat /etc/environment`. Use copy/paste. Not into the comment please. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them. Let me know when you have this info for me.

Comment: Don't use `/etc/environment` for setting locale variables. Use `/etc/default/locale` instead. Also, it would be great if you could let us know where you got the advice to include `UTF-8` that way.

Answer (score 2):

You modified the wrong file.

Edit `/etc/environment` back to original...

In `terminal`:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/environment
```

Change this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

To this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" # leave this line as is
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 # remove this line
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 # remove this line
```

The file that you wanted to modify is `/etc/default/locale`... but not by editing it manually. It already contains `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`.

You'll need to tell us more about what/why you were trying to modify your system.